# How to create aggregation in kafka consumer using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Hi I have written kafka consumer app using python with module `from kafka import KafkaConsumer`

Now I have json fields as below which is consumed,

```
{
  "user": "bob",
  "src_ip": "45.6.7.2"
 }
```

Now, How can I consume the messages for every 5 or 10 min (configurable time) and then check if each user's src IP is the same within the given time. If it's different then I have to send to save it in DB or send to different place via REST POST.

How can I achieve this using python consumer app?

Comment: Does it have to be in Python? Sounds like a stream processing requirement which might be better addressed e.g. with KSQL (via a REST API that you could access in Python)

Comment: Yes I also read abou KSQL, can you give me some example link where I can search. The basic docs just say how to create strem but not any where shows the create stream with window time. Also while create stream I need to provide schema but I want all json and no need to creae a schema again

Comment: Just consume every message and save messages in 10 min interval (using a while loop) in a list of the dictionary (because the data format is JSON) and at the end of the interval easily do your desired logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! To get the timestamp of the message, try `msg.timestamp` .

To make sure that each user's data is always routed to the same partition (and so it will always be processed by the same consumer), use `key=data["user"]` when you are producing the messages.

Finally, you will need to be aware that over the life of a consumer app, partition assignments may change. So think about what to do when a consumer crashes or loses its assignment in the middle of one of the 5 or 10 min windows. Does losing context matter? If not, you can probably use a simple in-memory data store per consumer. If losing context does matter, you may want to consider alternate strategies using periodic manual offset commits, or using a central datastore.